# Fixed width website the only real possibility?

Tags: css, web

When creating a web-site design, is the only real option to provide a fixed content width?

I notice most major websites (this one included) center all the content into a fixed width, which ensures all elements look correct on all screen sizes.

I think I already know the answer to this, but a colleague seems to think that there should never be a horizontal scrollbar and a website should resize to the users screen width.  I make the argument that text can resize but other elements can’t (buttons, textboxes etc), so a fixed width is the only option.

I'd love your opinions each way.

Surely fixed width is the only way you can guarantee the correct layout on ALL browsers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get clever with floats/media queries to make layouts work well at narrower widths.

But it is indeed more common to go with a fixed width:

- It’s easier to design
- Not many people have narrow monitors these days — most websites seem to assume they’ve got 1000 pixels of horizontal space to work with, and I haven’t heard of them getting many complaints
- Touch-based OSs (iOS, Android et. al) make zooming web pages feel very natural, so pixel dimensions aren't quite as important there.
- When lines of content get too wide (I think more than around 60 words?), they get difficult to read, so there’s not much advantage to be gained from having elements expand to full width for users who have bigger browser windows.

I think the most likely group of users to have less horizontal space available is smartphone users, and you’re going to want a specific design for them if you care that much about their experience.

Oh, just one thing though: “Surely fixed width is the only way you can guarantee the correct layout on ALL browsers?” With the greatest possible respect, that’s a bit of a programmer’s way to think about it. You can’t *guarantee* anything about web page rendering. Browsers and operating systems can do whatever they want. That’s the web. Let it go.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean guarantee, I meant most safest option.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic-width web-sites are generally composed of one or many percentage-width blocks which make 100% total. So blocks size change with resolution or browser resizing, but if total width is too short it can occure lisibility problems, so a minimal width is specified for `<body>`, in which case a horizontal scrollbar appears.
But you can think differently : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/14/will-horizontal-layouts-return/.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to make my websites have a minimum width for legibility, but otherwise the width is determined as a percentage of the window size (I normally pick 80%).

I find this gives me ample coverage of the viewport, whilst still looking good on larger monitors.

I find this approach fails on larger screens when there is little content, as the content tends to get stretched into a line at the top of the page, which can make things confusing. So for those pages it can be good to have a fixed width, centred style.

Answer (score 0):

No. A thousand times no.

If your website presents any kind of body text, fixed width is an abomination from the depths of the mid-90s, forcing readers to scroll like crazy, while being mocked by vast expanses of unused screen space to either size. (Now, a variable number of **columns** I might buy.)

BTW: flag for CW.

Comment: SO contains lots of text - but everythings centred in the middle fixed width.  How do you explain this?

Comment: Not the unused screen space argument again. The world is not running out of pixels. It is not hard to hit space bar to get your browser to scroll a page. It *is* hard to read content beyond a certain line length (studies have been done). It *is* tiresome to resize your browser window to make the line lengths readable.

Comment: -1. You do realize that there is a certain range of width with which reading is comfortable, and that anything narrower or wider makes reading harder? The readability and unused space arguments are both counter-factual and irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul, Yi: yep. Hint: seen any newspapers recently? It's a shame CSS didn't think ahead to make columns easy. But then, I'm probably silly to want to use web pages for information. Let's all look at the pretty pictures instead!

Comment: @Pontus: “It's a shame CSS didn't think ahead to make columns easy.” It’s really not. Columns on web pages go like this. 1. Read visible portion of column one. 2. Scroll down as much as required whilst reading the rest of column one. 3. Scroll back up to the top of column two, which may not be at the top of the page, to continue reading. 4. Repeat for as many columns as the page has. I’ve read PDFs on my computer that were laid out with multiple columns, and it was freaking annoying, whether the columns contained words, pretty pictures, or ugly pictures.

Comment: @Paul: and that's the **only** way of implementing columns you can imagine? Amazing.

Comment: @Pontus: Enlighten us with your vision of columns that’s easier to read on-screen than one column.

Comment: @Paul: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/, specifying desired column width, with overflow handled by vertical page scrolling by the viewport height. Extensions for content-requested width hints and variable column widths (for e.g. embedded illustrations) would be welcome, but not critical. 

...or, more simply put: use mostly the same conventions which are well established in print and therefore well-tested and well-known, but use the dynamicism of the web to optimize the layout to the actual display media. Don't force me to view everything through a keyhole, please.

Comment: @Pontus: all that to avoid hitting the space bar?

Comment: @Paul: all that to scan text quickly and efficiently. De gustibus non est disputandum, eh?

Comment: @Pontus: yeah. I guess. I was thinking of the problems with columns for reading. For scanning, yeah, better to have more stuff in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal scrollbars are a big problem.   A properly designed website should be able to scale down to be used on small resolution screens (640x480).  Also, it's nice to have to have my browser window maximized just to browse a site.  Also, there's no reason why a person with a high resolution monitor shouldn't be able to use the extra space their monitor gives them.